# LibGDX dragging on latest android versions

Tags: java, android, libgdx, drag

I'm creating a game using LibGDX, the game it was finished, but when I started testing on different Android smartphones, I discovered that the game runs with no problem on the old Android versios like 2.. but when I tested it on the latest Android versions like 3 or 4, the box has dragging problems, and I dont really know how to fix it, cos it works well on some old Android versions...

Here's the code I use to drag the box on the InputHandler file:

```
 @Override
    public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {

        miBox.onClick( screenX, screenY );
        return false;
    }
```

On the box handler file:

```
public void onClick(int screenX, int screenY) { 
    if (position.y < (originalY-100)){
                position.x=screenX;
    }
}
```

I was wondering if it could be a problem on the manifest file or something related with it... what do you think?.

If you know what I could be doing wrong, i would like you to comment! Thanks

Comment: please define "dragging problem". Is the box not moving at all? Is it moving, but not the way you expected it? device destroys itself after touching the box?

Comment: jajaa i forgot to mention the most important part of the question, this is what happens on a dragging problem: when you try to drag a box, you just lose in the game, cos you dragged it to the wrong place, I mean: you drag it to the top, and the game thinks it was moved to the left, and you lose. it's clear now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with the android version, is with the android screen size, you need to translate your screen coords to world coords.

```
Vector3 touchPos = new Vector3(screenX, screenY, 0);
camera.unproject(touchPos);
float x=touchPos.x, y=touchPost.y;
```

And now use x and y.

And don't forget that initializing objects every frame is not a good ideea, i would declare my vector3 somewhere and just set its x y and z (z being 0 always ) coords every frame.

Comment: Thanks Boldijar for your response! I come back again with some bad news, i tested the game on a new galaxy tab 3 (10 inches and the latest android version), and the game works good, so i think the problem is not on the android version, or the screen size, and maybe i'm dragging the box with an inaccurate code, so I need some help with it: I have to create a box every 2 seconds, that's moving to the bottom of the screen, and the used must be able to drag it, do yo have any idea for a efficient code?

Comment: Just a class with a x and y..in the update method every ball is going down (y -= some speed) , and if you touch your ball set its position to the touch position.. that's all